# Convert ORACLE NUMBER field to ORACLE DATE

Tags: java, date, oracle10g

I have a problem with converting NUMBER field to `ORACLE` date.
The problem is field holds a value 1285666505575 which consists of 13 digits.
I thought that this is standard timestamp value but current timestamp time consists of 10 digits (check it [here](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/)).
The field is set from `JAVA` code.
I would like to convert this number to `dd-mm-yyyy` human format.
Could you give some suitable advises?

Thanks in advance!

With help of @Jesper i found [this](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-convert-milliseconds-to-the-proper-date-format) solution.

```
select TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + (1285666505575 /1000/60/60/24) from dual
```

Comment: What date is that supposed to represent?

Comment: @Ic. this is the date of last row's modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unix timestamp (that your link refers to) counts the number of **seconds** since 01-01-1970.

Java counts the time using a number of **milliseconds** since 01-01-1970. So it's not a surprise that this has three digits more than the Unix timestamp.

You can pass that number to the constructor of `java.util.Date`. Example:

```
Date date = new Date(1285666505575L);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date));
```

Comment: i want to know how to convert it in Oracle